# Stopping React from Refreshing when a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I am making an online drinking game. I have added a hamburger icon at the top of the page and when it is pressed, it is refreshing the data inside of the cards. I have used this to randomly generate what the cards say.

```
    const cards = [
        {
            title: 'Your Knicked!',
            description: 'You have been caught by the guard and sentenced to 5 drinks! ',
            dice_roll_desc: 'Roll above a 15 to escape!'
        },
        {
            title: 'Goblin Boss!',
            description: 'You have stumbled upon the goblin boss, he tells you to neck your      poisoned drink! ',
            dice_roll_desc: 'Roll above a 10 to defeat him! or else, neck your poisoned drink'
        }, 
    ]
    const randomValue = cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length)]
```

There are more cards than this, and there are more components of different types of cards too but they all are stored like this. This is in a component called "PinkGameCards.jsx. The component called "DrinkingGame.jsx" does this to pick what color card to use.

```
           {num >= 1 && num <= 2 ?
                <BlackGameCards /> : null // Black -  2% chance
            }
            {num >= 3 && num <= 23 ?
                <GreenGameCards /> : null  // Green -  21% chance
            }
            {num >= 24 && num <= 32 ?
                <OrangeGameCards /> : null // Orange -  9% chance
            }
            {num >= 33 && num <= 51 ?
                <BlueGameCards /> : null // Blue -  19% chance
            }
            {num >= 52 && num <= 65 ?
                <RedGameCards /> : null // Red -  14% chance
            }
```

It randomly picks a card when the "next card" button is pressed.However, it also randomly picks a card when the hamburger menu button is pressed. How do I stop this?

I have tried using use effect and prevent default to fix this but I cant seem to figure it out. Im not sure if this is a simple fix or a bit more complex. I've been upskilling in JavaScript by myself so im not particularly confident in it when it comes to things like this.

Comment: There is zero React code shown here, so it's not really possible to see what you have done wrong.  If you can knock up a reproducible snippet, that will really help others to help you.